# ADT eclipse and SDK Folder

Tags: android, sdk, adt, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-manager

to clarify, the problem is ADT doesnt install the sdk folder anymore, and also, doesnt support any of the sdk manager above their last version... you can try to look up a sdk manager version that suits ADT, but good look with that. The only way to use eclipse with android sdk is to copy another eclipse well configured with de sdk manager folder, from another PC.
How can I use Eclipse, not Android Studio? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I understand that you have to work with it, but did you miss that they dropped support for Eclipse about 2 years ago? Your problem is not going to be fixed by Google

Comment: i found out just now, becose on some bug that i needed to fix, and by mistake i delete the android sdk that ADT used, and now i am in this situation of translading the eclipse from another computer... is not my decition work with this shit.. is from my company choise

Comment: one only investigate something, wenn that something become relevant to the person itself..

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, Google no longer supports Eclipse, they support Android Studio, which is based off of IntelliJ.  Either switch to Android Studio or one of the community efforts like Andmore https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore that attempt to support Android independently.